# Representation of a vector in the HHL algorithm

Tags: hhl-algorithm, terminology-and-notation

Reading about the HHL algorithm, which is used to solve the equation $Ax=b$, on Wikipedia, they say to represent $b$ as
$|b\rangle=\sum_{i \mathop =1}^N b_i|i\rangle.$

I'm assuming $b$ is a vector with coefficients $\{b_i\}$.

What do the $\{|i\rangle\}$ represent in reality? Shouldn't they be a basis for $\mathbb{C}^N$ (assuming we are working with complex-valued linear systems)? Are we just using the notation $1, 2, 3, ..., N$ as a label for these basis vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $|i\rangle$ is in fact decimal representation of a binary number (or, computational basis quantum state with index $i$ to be precise). For example $|5\rangle$ is a computational basis state $|101\rangle$ for a three-qubit system or $|0101\rangle$ for a four-qubit system etc. These basis states can be represented as vectors in space $\mathbb{C}^N$. For example $|101\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}^T$. As you can see, from $N = 8$ members of the vector, only the 6th (5+1 as we are counting from 0) one is equal 1. Similarly you can represent another states $|i\rangle$ for different number of qubits $n = \log_2 N$. You now see that $|i\rangle$ is a quantum state notation behind which a standard basis of space $\mathbb{C}^N$ is "hidden".

This all means that the expression $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}b_i|i\rangle$ is simply a linear combination of vectors in space $\mathbb{C}^N$ standard basis with coefficient of the combination equal $b_i \in \mathbb{C}$.